# GParted fs check wiped disk - possible to undo?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, gparted, fsck, fat32

I connected a fat32-formatted USB drive to my system. `dmesg` showed:

```
[ 4057.783200] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
...
[ 4064.091218] FAT-fs (sdd1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

The drive's used with MacOS, Win and Linux, hence fat32. This has happened a couple of times before as there's been short power cuts. As usual I used Gparted to check the disk, being too lazy to `man fsck` to check out the options:

[image: gparted]

This time however it didn't just check the disk, it wiped it completely. Syslog tells me nothing:

```
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.248434] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.269705] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a, bcdDevice= 7.10
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.269712] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.269716] usb 2-3: Product: Expansion
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.269719] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Seagate
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.269722] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: NAA9700F
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.277694] scsi host6: uas
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.278676] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0710 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Mar  4 11:24:28 TREX kernel: [ 4053.280001] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Mar  4 11:24:32 TREX kernel: [ 4057.782355] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
Mar  4 11:24:32 TREX kernel: [ 4057.782361] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
Mar  4 11:24:32 TREX kernel: [ 4057.782547] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
Mar  4 11:24:32 TREX kernel: [ 4057.782552] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Mar  4 11:24:32 TREX kernel: [ 4057.782880] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Mar  4 11:24:32 TREX kernel: [ 4057.783200] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
Mar  4 11:24:33 TREX kernel: [ 4058.118689]  sdd: sdd1
Mar  4 11:24:33 TREX kernel: [ 4058.142221] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
Mar  4 11:24:39 TREX kernel: [ 4064.091218] FAT-fs (sdd1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Mar  4 11:24:39 TREX udisksd[1033]: Mounted /dev/sdd1 at /media/pg1/E93B-1A8F on behalf of uid 1001
Mar  4 11:25:01 TREX CRON[5945]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar  4 11:25:49 TREX systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar  4 11:25:49 TREX kernel: [ 4134.948332] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, quota, no debug enabled
Mar  4 11:26:05 TREX systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar  4 11:26:35 TREX systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar  4 11:26:55 TREX udisksd[1033]: Cleaning up mount point /media/pg1/E93B-1A8F (device 8:49 is not mounted)
Mar  4 11:26:55 TREX systemd[1807]: media-pg1-E93B\x2d1A8F.mount: Succeeded.
Mar  4 11:26:55 TREX systemd[1]: media-pg1-E93B\x2d1A8F.mount: Succeeded.
```

`/var/log/messages` and `journald` aren't any more helpful. The disk itself is fine, it's just empty instead of containing the data I've stored there.

The disk is unmounted. Is there any way to recover the data?

Command `sudo systemctl cat media-pg1-E93B\x2d1A8F.mount` reports `No files found for media-pg1-E93Bx2d1A8F.mount.` I remounted the disk and rerun the command, but it returned nothing. Syslog after remounting:

```
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.682162] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xh>
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.703495] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=23>
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.703502] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialN>
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.703506] usb 2-3: Product: Expansion
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.703509] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Seagate
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.703512] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: NAA9700F
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.713388] scsi host6: uas
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.714278] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        >
Mar  4 19:23:50 TREX kernel: [32814.715560] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.079622] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.0>
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.079628] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.079849] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.079855] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.080229] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enable>
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.080516] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not>
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.416147]  sdd: sdd1
Mar  4 19:23:54 TREX kernel: [32819.455923] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk

pg1@TREX:~$ sudo systemctl cat media-pg1-E93B\x2d1A8F.mount
No files found for media-pg1-E93Bx2d1A8F.mount.

pg1@TREX:~$ sudo systemctl cat media-pg1-E93B\\x2d1A8F.mount
No files found for media-pg1-E93B\x2d1A8F.mount.
```

Comment: *As usual I let Gparted do the work.* - what work? Why did you use it instead of `fsck.fat`? What's in `/media/pg1/E93B-1A8F`? It looks like it's all fine.

Comment: Updated the question, including the "why", which IMHO isn't really relevant when question is whether data can be recovered :-)

Comment: Syslog indicates you have two separate subsystems attempting to mount the disk, which can cause some confusion: `udisksd` had it mounted at `/media/pg1/E93B-1A8F`, and later `systemd`'s `media-pg1-E93B\x2d1A8F.mount` unit is activating to mount the same filesystem to some unknown location. What does `systemctl cat media-pg1-E93B\x2d1A8F.mount` report?

Comment: @telcoM - reports "No files found". Question updated.

Comment: Hmm.. you might have to double the backslash, as it is a special character for the shell. Try `systemctl cat media-pg1-E93B\\x2d1A8F.mount` too, please.

Comment: @telcoM - nope, still the same. I know this system is f-d up after I accidentally did a test on my actual daily driver instead of the test VM - destructive operation in the wrong terminal. I'm just about to restore it from the latest Clonezilla image for about 2 months now :-D My prob is that I _just_ managed to recover about 200GB of data on this disk from a sort of a ghost drive - a directory that disappeared at aforementioned f-up decided to remount itself as a new drive during bootup, but only that one time...